# Error: Unreachable statement and Missing return statement?

Tags: java, recursion, return

I'm trying to create an overridden compareTo method that will compare two String values and sort which comes first alphabetically, and I'm trying to implement it recursively, but I'm running into trouble with my return and if statements:

```
public class Recursion{

private static int index = 0;

public static int compareTo(String string1,String string2){
    char character1 = string1.toLowerCase().charAt(index);
    char character2 = string2.toLowerCase().charAt(index);

    if (character1 < character2 || string1.length() > string2.length()){
        System.out.println("String 1 comes after String 2");
        return -1;

    }
    else if(character1 > character2 || string1.length() < string2.length()){
        System.out.println("String 1 comes before String 2");
        return 1;
    }
    if (string1.length() == string2.length()){
        index ++;
        System.out.println("Index is " +index);
        return 0;
        return compareTo(string1,string2);
    }
```

I'm getting compiler errors "Unreachable statement" on the recursive if statement at the bottom, as well as a "missing return statement" from that same if block.

Comment: After you `return 0;` - `return compareTo(string1,string2);` becomes unreachable, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are getting,

> "Unreachable statement"

because inside the if condition you are returning 0 so, the subsequent

> `return compareTo(string1,string2);`

is not reachable.

> ```
>     if (string1.length() == string2.length()){
>         index ++;
>         System.out.println("Index is " +index);
>         return 0;
>         return compareTo(string1,string2);
>     }
> ```

2. You are getting,

> "missing return statement"

because, you are not returning a value for all the cases. Such as what if the following statement is false?

> if (string1.length() == string2.length()){

3. I don't think your algorithm is that correct. Please find the below sample for your reference.

   private static int index = 0;

   public static int compareTo(String string1,String string2){
       //char character1 = string1.toLowerCase().charAt(index); //String index out of range: Error may occur
       //char character2 = string2.toLowerCase().charAt(index); //String index out of range: Error may occur

   ```
   char character1, character2;

   int maxIndex=-1;

   if(string1.length()<=string2.length()) {
       maxIndex=string1.length()-1;
   } else {
       maxIndex=string2.length()-1;
   }

   if(index<=maxIndex) {
       character1 = string1.toLowerCase().charAt(index);
       character2 = string2.toLowerCase().charAt(index);

       if (character1!=character2) {
           return character1-character2;
       } else {
           if(index==maxIndex) {
               return string1.length()-string2.length();
           } else {
               ++index;
               return compareTo(string1,string2);
           }
       }
   } else {
       return string1.length()-string2.length();
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

About why you are getting the Unreachable statement:

```
return 0
return compareTo(string1,string2) <<<<< this line is unreachable because of the above return 0;
```

About why you are getting the missing return statement:
If no one conditions inside the three blocks are true you don't have a return statement outside them so the compiler is complaining this missing return.
You'll have to put a last return statement out of everything.

About the algorithm.. I thing your idea is a completely mistake and won't works.. Try to rewrite using other algorithm.

```
if (character1 < character2 || string1.length() > string2.length()){
```

Why are you returning -1 if char1 < char2 OR the string1 has less character than string2? I can't figure out what the size of the string has to do with sorting alphabetically.